# Are these equal in terms of efficiency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I never questioned any efficiency difference between the following two scripts:

DateKey is type `INT`

1.

```
DECLARE @StartDate  INT = 20130101,
        @EndDate    INT = 20130201

SELECT  UserAccountKey,
        income_LT = SUM(ISNULL(income,0.0)) 
INTO    #x
FROM    WH.dbo.xxx x
WHERE   x.DateKey > = @StartDate
        AND x.DateKey < @EndDate
GROUP BY    UserAccountKey
```

Execution for the above is:

[image]

2.

```
SELECT  UserAccountKey,
        income_LT = SUM(ISNULL(income,0.0)) 
INTO    #x
FROM    WH.dbo.xxx x
WHERE   x.DateKey > = 20130101
        AND x.DateKey < 20130201
GROUP BY    UserAccountKey
```

Here is the execution plan for number 2:
[image]

`1.` is a lot faster (2 seconds compared to 80 seconds) - is this as expected? Why?

Comment: Is this running on a stored procedure?. What if you add this hint on the second query?: `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`

Comment: Is there any reason for storing dates as integers rather than as dates? `Date` is 1 byte smaller than `int` and also ensures you can't store nonsense "dates" such as `20130231` (as well as being usable in the various `datetime` functions)

Comment: Also you don't need the `ISNULL` since SQL Server ignores `NULL` for aggregates.  I'm not sure if it will get optimized out or not but it's unneeded.

Comment: @JNK - The one difference is that it means you don't see the `Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.` message.

Comment: @MartinSmith not my warehouse : don't want to upset the `dba` by mentioning that the dates should be `date` rather than `int`

Comment: @whytheq - Mouse over the arrow out of the top clustered index seek on the bottom plan. What is the actual vs estimated number of rows?

Comment: @MartinSmith 9million actual rows compared to 1 estimated row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first query it uses variables. The value of these is not known at compilation time so it produces a plan based on generic estimates. On the second one it compiles a plan based on the actual parameter values.

The fact that the generic guesses work out better than the plan where it knows the specific values indicates that probably your statistics need updating.

Likely last time they were updated few if any rows matched the `WHERE DateKey > = 20130101         AND DateKey < 20130201` predicate but now many do.

This is a common issue with [ascending date columns](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/)

[See also this question and answers on the dba site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/33698/3690)

**Edit** This can be seen in the plan here

[image]

The thickness of the lines indicate the number of rows. The very thin line to the left of the compute scalar shows the estimated number of rows (actual row counts often aren't shown for compute scalars [for the reasons here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180423042943/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/05/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.aspx)). The very thick lines into the compute scalar and out of the sort represent the actual number of rows. The two are clearly very different.

As well as choosing an inappropriate plan (serial with nested loops join) this poor estimate also means that the sort spilled to disc as the query requested an insufficient memory grant (shown by the warning triangle).

Comment: hello Martin - we had a server upgrade last week. "your statistics need updating" ..I'm just a data analysts - will this term mean something to the DBA? We load data every day into the warehouse although I suppose the Date dimension is always loaded

Comment: @whytheq - If you look at the execution plan for the query with literal values you will likely find that the actual and estimated rows are very different. Yes the DBA should know what that means.

Comment: I'll add a section of the ex plan to the OP. It's doing 41% on a `Sort`

Comment: @whytheq - Showing a picture of the explain plan isn't going to very informative. Costs shown in the plan are based on estimates and the estimates are probably wrong. Either upload the entire plan XML (for the actual plan not the estimated one) or show the output of `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON`

Comment: +1 thanks for all the help - not really resolved but I guess I need to learn a lot more about execution plans; I've got a good book by `Itzak ban...` that should be a good start

Comment: @whytheq - What's not resolved? I told you hours ago you need to update your statistics.

Comment: +1 @martin_smith ... just back of my hols - `not resolved` because I asked the DBA to update the statistics, and he told me he did, but it didn't make any difference. He might have misinterpretted my request. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @whytheq - He can't have updated them. The plan clearly shows they are wrong with the  9 million actual rows compared to 1 estimated row

Comment: @martin_smith - THANKS MARTIN, NOW MY DBA IS A BIT P*SSED OFF WITH AT ME FOR FINDING A WAREHOUSE PROBLEM. (.....it worked though !). Turns out it was the statistics on our main fact table! I wonder why they aren't updating automatically in the daily load?